# Вывод профиля из соцсети на сайт

Tags: вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Доброго времени суток!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, хочу в заметке (материале) Wordpress указать ссылку на профиль в соцсети. Возможно ли сделать отображение этой ссылки как миниатюры профиля? Например, в комментариях так бывает - отображается фото и имя с фамилией профиля.
В общем нужно, чтобы ссылка отображалась не как текст, а как контейнер с более подробной информацией о профиле (город, возраст и пр., если указаны).
[Вот так](https://pp.vk.me/c623731/v623731860/1add/i-qlNG3XMTk.jpg) 
В каждой записи будет разный профиль.

Попробовал через PHP:

```
$request = 'http://api.vkontakte.ru/method/users.get?uids=1&f..,status';
$response = file_get_contents($request);
$info = array_shift(json_decode($response)->response);

var_dump($info->photo_200);
var_dump($info->status);
```

Но выдает такой результат:

```
string(47) «http://cs9591.vk.me/v9591001/72/NBRJW_81WaM.jpg»
string(9) «道德經»
```

А нужно в том виде, как указанно в ссылке :(

Если неправильно выразился, поправьте.
Благодарю за внимание.

Answer (score 1):

Чему удивляетесь? Иероглифам? У Павла Дурова http://vk.com/id1 такой статус (道德經) на самом деле.

```
$vk_info = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?uids=1&fields=photo_200,status'), true);

print_r($vk_info);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [response] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [uid] => 1
                    [first_name] => Павел
                    [last_name] => Дуров
                    [photo_200] => http://cs9591.vk.me/v9591001/72/NBRJW_81WaM.jpg
                    [status] => 道德經
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Я хочу понять, как придать правильный вид тому, что выводится.  
В ссылке я указал, что хотелось бы получить... https://pp.vk.me/c623731/v623731860/1add/i-qlNG3XMTk.jpg  
Грубо говоря, как "красиво вывести эти данные" на страницу, например, wordpress?  
Благодарю, что отозвался.

Comment: @Koka51, примерно как-то так http://jsfiddle.net/pa4jor9h/

Comment: @ModaL, Это Спасибо!
Подскажи пожалуйса насчет организации такого момента:
Хотим разместить запись через wordpress.
В записи есть необходимость указывать профиль из соц.сети, чтобы он выводился как ты показал в ссылке.
Т.е. можно как-нибудь упростить этот процесс, а не прописывать все вручную постоянно?
Например какойто шорт-код вводим (или как это правильно назвать),добавляем в него только id пользователя нас интересующего, и нам выдаст на странице готовый результат?
Благодарю за внимание.

Comment: @Koka51, функции же. К примеру:

>> function vk_info($id = null) {
 return 'profile';
}

Вызов:

>> echo vk_info(1);

Comment: @ModaL, благодарю! А подскажи, в джумле силен? adsmanager?